# What is the difference between p and &p in Go when p is a pointer?

Tags: pointers, go

I'm aware of what difference in Go pointer's address.

```
var int *a = new(int)
```

I can define pointer variable like this.
When I check this variable's address, I found out another address.

```
fmt.Println(a, &a)
```

I'd like to know what difference in those address.`enter code here`

Answer (score 3):

`a` is a variable of pointer type, which means the data it holds is a memory address. So printing `a` prints the memory address it holds, the address of the variable it points to.

And `a` being a variable, it is stored somewhere in memory, `a` itself also has an address and `&a` is that address.

So you have 2 variables: `a` and the one created by `new(int)`, whose address is returned by `new()` and which address we store in `a`.

Please read this for a clear and short introduction to pointers:

[Dave Cheney: Understand Go pointers in less than 800 words or your money back](https://dave.cheney.net/2017/04/26/understand-go-pointers-in-less-than-800-words-or-your-money-back)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
By the way, I have another a question.
When I use pointer variable, is it okay that I don't need to concern about pointer's address?
for example,
var a *int = new(int)
&a <- this address. is not a's address